# why date.getHours() is not working inside a firebase cloud function

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm starting out on firebase cloud functions that takes date and returns the 'hours' part of that data

here's my function

```
export const getFees = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.date);
    console.log(data.date.name);

    let date: Date = data.date;

    console.log(date);

    let hours = date.getHours();

    console.log(hours);

    return hours;

})
```

I run the function through the firebase functions:shell command
i enter these commands then i run the function

```
> now = new Date();
> data = { date: now };
> getFees(data);
```

but i get this error message:

```
firebase > getFees(data)
Sent request to function.
firebase > >  (node:90195) ExperimentalWarning: The http2 module is an experimental API.
>  [object Object]
>  2019-08-10T22:03:25.885Z
>  
>  2019-08-10T22:03:25.885Z
>  Unhandled error TypeError: date.getHours is not a function
>      at exports.getFees.functions.https.onCall
```

Comment: Can you please try with the `new` keyword, like follows: `let hours = (new Date(date)).getHours();`? It should work.

Comment: That worked ! Using your help, I had to apply new Date(data.date) in orders for the getHours function to work. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Try it with the `new` keyword, like follows:

```
let hours = (new Date(date)).getHours();.
```

Contrary to popular belief, the `new` keyword is more than just sugar: it means that to prototype is bounded to `this.__proto__`, instead of just returned as an object that is called while evaluation. In this case,  `.getHours` is a [prototype function](https://link.medium.com/Z5DrvtvG3Y), so if we don't invoke `Date()` with `new`, it's not going to be properly binded. This is the main issue you were facing - `Date` creates a date object with or without `new`, but it won't necessarily be binded with the prototype functions.

I feel like you already understood that you *needed* to create a Date object, but just missed this keyword. However, in short, if Firebase Functions is being called via `get`/`post`, there's two ways of passing it data:

1. Query parameters - strings and boolean only
2. `request.body` - in normal encoding (i.e not `.../form-data`), only default datatypes (no invoked constructors): strings, integers, booleans, arrays and floats.

See, none of these formats allow you to pass date objects, so we need to use `new Date(data.date)` to get the date, currently a string, as a date *type*.

Answer (score 0):

The date that reaches your function is not an instance of Date; as you can see in the logs it's a stringified representation of it, that's why the method is not available, and also why you have to 'reconstruct' it, as suggested by Geza Kerecsenyi.

---

> Remember that your data is traversing the Internet from your code to Firebase, so actual instances can't be sent, but some sort of data exchange format, like strings, or JSON, and the like, this is why the Date you created in your app doesn't actually reach the Firebase function.